# "move two inches" vs. "move by two inches"

Tags: adverbs

> He walks **two kilometers** every day.

Is **two kilometers** a adverb here?

Which is more appropriate:

> He moved **two inches.**
>
> He moved **by two inches.**

Explain.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence *He walks two kilometers every day*, *He* is a subject,*walks* is a transitive verb,*two kilometers* is a noun,*every day* is an adverb. So the structure of this sentence is subject + transitive verb + noun + adverb.

*He moved two inches* should be the more appropriate than *He moved by two inches*
*He* is a subject, *moved* is a transitive verb,*two inches* is a noun. The structure of this sentence is subject + transitive verb + noun. Please refer to the explanation of [Move](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/move) and take a look at *I'm so cold I can't move my fingers*

Comment: *He moved a foot* can be parsed in two completely different ways. 1) He moved *one of his feet* (or feasibly even someone else's foot, in a contrived context), and 2) He moved [himself] *a distance of* one foot (12 inches). Syntactically, I'd say the NP in #2 is functioning *adverbially*, even if it looks a bit like a noun.